# jqPlot loading via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqplot

I don't think I'm understanding JSON completely, here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseurl + "analytics/grab_points"
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var line1=$.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(line1);
            var plot2 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', line1, {
                title: 'Customized Date Axis',
                gridPadding: {right: 35},
                axes: {
                    xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                        tickOptions: {formatString: '%b %#d, %y'},
                        min: 'May 30, 2008',
                        tickInterval: '1 month'
                    }
                },
                series: [{lineWidth: 4, markerOptions: {style: 'square'}}]
            });
        });
```

jqPlot seems to expect data like so:

```
[['2008-06-28 8:00AM', 4], ['2008-6-30 8:00AM', 1], ['2008-8-30 8:00AM', 5.7]]
```

(that should the content in var **line1**)

My server side code (PHP):

```
$test=array(
            "2008-06-28 8:00AM" =>4,
            "2008-6-30 8:00AM" =>1,
            "2008-8-30 8:00AM" =>5.7,
        );

        echo json_encode($test);
```

My console logs:

```
{"2008-06-28 8:00AM":4,"2008-6-30 8:00AM":1,"2008-8-30 8:00AM":5.7} analytics:103
Object {2008-06-28 8:00AM: 4, 2008-6-30 8:00AM: 1, 2008-8-30 8:00AM: 5.7} analytics:105
Uncaught Error: No data specified
```

Pretty sure I'm going barbarian on this JSON (growing pains), any idea would be great.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the same structure that jqPlot wants you'll have to change your array in your php code...

jqPlot is expecting something like in your php array-structure:

```
$test = array(
    array("2008-06-28 8:00AM",4),
    array("2008-6-30 8:00AM",1)
);
```

check example 2 on http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php (the $c)

the {} you see is just because you output it as object rather than as array, but this should be the same as the [] (this is also explained on the php manual)

EDIT: also i don't think this line: `var line1=$.parseJSON(data);` is still needed because your `data` is already json.